# Flutter - Google Maps inside reorderable List

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, reorderable-list

I am using the [Reorderables Package](https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables) to create a reorder-able List with the [GoogleMaps](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) widget inside.
On long press to reorder the tiles, the GoogleMaps widget refreshes and the tile is not selected anymore.
`onReorderStarted` of `ReorderableColumn` is triggered but `onNoReorder` is triggered immediately after.

Here is is a code Example to reproduce the problem:

```dart
class MapTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapTest({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MapTest> createState() => _MapTestState();
}

class _MapTestState extends State<MapTest> {
  List<int> list = List.generate(2, (index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableColumn(
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {},
      children: list
          .asMap()
          .map((key, link) => MapEntry(
                key,
                Map(
                  key: ValueKey(key),
                ),
              ))
          .values
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}

class Map extends StatelessWidget {
  const Map({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AbsorbPointer(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 370 / 138,
          child: GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(36, 48),
              zoom: 12.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried the following:

- Make Map constant
- Show different widget on `buildDraggableFeedback`